# Excel 2016 - Apply Conditional Formatting based on value of a prefix label

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

Hi I am trying to apply conditional formatting using the following search function: -

=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("S",$C1))=TRUE

My problem is that the "S" has been applied using custom format to insert the letter "S" before a digit, so although the value of the cell is e.g. "7", it appears as "S7".

The problem is that it does not appear to recognise the prefix label, is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: We will be able to help you if you can post the custom format syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [following YouTube video by Leila](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGY70sdpaLc) to know how to add colors using custom formatting.

But if you can add the syntax that you used for custom formatting, I can check if it can be replicated using Conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you must show the CF engine the string as formatted. Usually you achieve this by simply referencing the cell of interest.

But since its formatting does not actually change the cell of interest, just how it looks on-screen, you need something more direct.

Use `TEXT()` to produce the actual string the format shows, then `LEFT()` to strip the starting character from the string. Now you are testing exactly what you are seeing.

In your formula, replace the target of the `SEARCH()` function (`$C1`) with:

```
LEFT(TEXT($C1,"\S#,##0.000"),1)
```

(of course, using the precise custom format string in place of my "\S#,##0.000" — edit the custom format and `Copy` the string, then `ESC` and `Paste` it into this formula)

Not every custom format works in `TEXT()` but mostly the ones I've seen fail to work are pretty arcane/bizarre, so I expect most normal-ish ones would. This one I gave DOES work in tests, so as long as the parts in your exact format that do not add the "S" are reasonably normal, you should end up happy.